# Split string with PHP piece by piece

Tags: php, string, split, tags, preg-split

I have a string that I want to split like this:

```
Sinn.und.Sinnlichkeit.1995.German.DL.1080p.BluRay.x264-RSG <--- Original string
Sinn.und.Sinnlichkeit.1995.German.DL.1080p.BluRay.x264 <--- no match
Sinn.und.Sinnlichkeit.1995.German.DL.1080p.BluRay <--- no match
Sinn.und.Sinnlichkeit.1995.German.DL.1080p <--- no match
Sinn.und.Sinnlichkeit.1995.German.DL <--- no match
Sinn.und.Sinnlichkeit.1995.German <--- no match
Sinn.und.Sinnlichkeit.1995  <--- no match
Sinn.und.Sinnlichkeit <--- match
Sinn.und <--- no match
Sinn <--- no match
```

Until it has a API match.

Can you help me with that? I tried with preg_split, but it's not really working...

```
$string = 'Sinn.und.Sinnlichkeit.1995.German.DL.1080p.BluRay.x264-RSG';

$split = preg_split('/[.-]/', $string);

foreach( $split AS $explode )
{
   echo $explode;
}
```

Comment: in other words are you trying to `substr` to the position of a 4 digit year?

Comment: not really, some strings don't have a year in it, that's why I want to split it until i have a API match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're splitting correct. All it takes is a for loop, building the required `$arr` from the parts as you go along.

```php
$string = 'Sinn.und.Sinnlichkeit.1995.German.DL.1080p.BluRay.x264-RSG';

$split = preg_split('/[.-]/', $string);
$arr = [];
$brr = [];
foreach( $split AS $explode)
{
   $arr[] = $explode;
   // check $arr or implode($arr) with api
   // or push to
   $brr[] = $arr;
}

$result = array_reverse($brr);
```